# How to use sys_read() in kernel space properly

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I wrote a system call that searches for the given input in a file. But my code is not working because `sys_read()` is not working.

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>

asmlinkage long sys_search_phrase(int fd, char *phrase, char *buffer, int line)
{
    printk("Search was here\n");
    char arr[] = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    char *temp = arr;
    int i = 0;
    int temp_line = 1;

    while(sys_read(fd, &temp[i], 1) == 1){
        if(temp[i] == '\n' || temp[i] == 0x0 || temp[i] == '\0'){
            temp[i] = 0;
            if(i != 0){
                //buffer now has a line
                if(line <= 0 && contains(temp, phrase)) {
                    copy(buffer, temp);
                    return temp_line;
                }
                else if(line == temp_line && contains(temp, phrase)) {
                    copy(buffer, temp);
                    return temp_line;
                }
                temp_line++;
            }
            i=0;
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So I tried to debug the code using `printk()` and found out that my program is never entering the `while` loop.

Kernel v4.4.202
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: When you say "`sys_read()` is not working", what does that mean?  Do you get unexpected output? What do you see?

Comment: Also note that `sys_read()` will expect a user-virtual address for the second parameter, you can't really supply that from the kernel.

Comment: I am taking file descriptor from user space and read is not working because while loop doesn't run.

Comment: What did you do try to debug the problem?  What, specifically, is `sys_read()` returning?

Comment: I used printk in while loop so every time it enters while it prints. But it never enters the loop.

Comment: I just want to read the file character by character I wrote the same code in user space there I used read() and it was working.

Comment: So I should provide buffer for sys_read from user space.

Comment: Yes, if the buffer into which you're reading can be provided by userspace, then that'd help.  Another option is to trace what `sys_read()` calls until you find what does the kernelspace->userspace copy.  There may be a kernel-facing API that does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call `sys_read()` with a buffer that lives in the kernel, it expects a user-virtual address for the second parameter.

There is a kernel API, [`kernel_read()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.202/source/fs/exec.c#L844), that you can use from kernel space.

Comment: Providing buffer for ``sys_read()`` from user space fixed the problem.